# How can I switch between two methods in one button with every click?

Tags: c#, .net

I am new on C# so sorry if it look easy for some of you :)

### I have this button click:

```
private void buttonSwitchCamera_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        _blManager.SendTrackerCmd(TrackerCmdType.PrimaryAVT_ActiveSensor, (float)IR_Id.IR_1); // Switch to IR1
        _blManager.SendTrackerCmd(TrackerCmdType.PrimaryAVT_ActiveSensor, (float)IR_Id.IR_2); // Switch to IR2
}
```

How can I switch between the two methods when clicking the button?

one click will be for method #1

second click will be for method #2

third click will be for method #1

etc..

Comment: You don't need to switch between 2 methods. You call the same method each time, but with different second parameter. You will need to add a member to your class, holding the last button state. According to the state you will select the proper second argument value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
bool executeMethodOne;

private void buttonSwitchCamera_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   executeMethodOne = !executeMethodOne;

   var IrId = executeMethodOne ? IR_Id.IR_1 : IR_Id.IR_2;

    _blManager.SendTrackerCmd(TrackerCmdType.PrimaryAVT_ActiveSensor, (float)IrId);
}
```

Have a `bool` called `executeMethodOne` which you will invert everytime you click on the button. Depending on if it is `true` or `false` you can execute the first or the second method

Answer (score 1):

First click is old:

```
    private void OnButtonClickOdd(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Unsubscribe OnButtonClickOdd
        button.Click -= OnButtonClickOdd;

        // Subcribe to OnButtonClickEven
        button.Click += OnButtonClickEven;

        // Do your job here
    }

    private void OnButtonClickEven(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Unsubscribe OnButtonClickEven
        button.Click -= OnButtonClickEven;

        // Subcribe to OnButtonClickOdd
        button.Click += OnButtonClickOdd;

        // Do your job here
    }
```

Other way: just use bool flag to know it odd or even click:

```
private bool odd = true;

private void buttonSwitchCamera_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(old)
    {
         // Odd click job
    }
    else
    {
         // Even click job
    }
    old = !old;
}
```

Comment: You have named your `bool` `odd` but in the code you use `old` as a `bool`